# How to override Default cell editor in a jTable?

Tags: java, swing, fonts, jtable, editmode

I want to change the properties of `DefaultCellEditor` in a jTable so that I can customize the font type, size, color, background color etc of a cell in edit mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
table.setDefaultEditor(Object.class, customEditor)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set your own cell editor which is probably derived from the `DefaultCellEditor`. Use

```
     table.getColumnModel().getColumn(column).setCellEditor(myEditor);
```

To set your editor into the table.

Comment: but it's for a particular column i want it for every cell.

Comment: i repeated the line for every column and it worked !! thanks @Sergiy Medvynskyy